# Multi-dimension instance loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, haml

I am trying to use a custom sql query to display different attributes for a product i.e. Size and Price. The query I have when running in console displays as it should

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, variant_properties.description, LEFT(variant_properties.description,1) as short_desc, variants.price FROM products
  INNER JOIN product_properties ON product_properties.product_id = products.id
  INNER JOIN variant_properties on product_properties.property_id = variant_properties.property_id AND variant_properties."primary" = true
  INNER JOIN properties ON properties.id = product_properties.property_id AND properties.id = variant_properties.property_id AND properties.display_name = 'Size'
  INNER JOIN variants on variants.product_id = products.id AND variants.id = variant_properties.variant_id
```

[image]

In my HAML template I have done the following

```
- @products.each_with_index do |product, i|
  .product-list.grid-block
    .small-8.grid-content.text-center
      %h4= product.name.titlecase
      - @sizes.each do |size|
        = link_to size.short_desc, product, class: 'hollow button tiny'
        %small= size.price
```

and in the controller

```
products = Product.active
    # products = Product.active.includes(:variants)

    product_types = nil
    if params[:product_type_id].present? && product_type = ProductType.find_by_id(params[:product_type_id])
      product_types = product_type.self_and_descendants.map(&:id)
    end
    if product_types
      @products = products.where(product_type_id: product_types)
    else
      @products = products
    end

      @sizes = Product.find_by_sql("SELECT products.id, LEFT(variant_properties.description,1) as short_desc, variants.price FROM products
  INNER JOIN product_properties ON product_properties.product_id = products.id
  INNER JOIN  variant_properties on product_properties.property_id = variant_properties.property_id
  INNER JOIN properties ON properties.id = product_properties.property_id AND properties.id = variant_properties.property_id AND properties.display_name = 'Size'
  INNER JOIN  variants on variants.product_id = products.id AND variants.id = variant_properties.variant_id")
```

Ideally I am trying to get it to look something like below, though I am having issues achieving this

[image]

Comment: What's your question again?

Comment: @HoangPhan added more details

Comment: Ah I understand, you want to display the attributes from other tables but `Product.find_by_sql` only give you the list of products right?

Comment: @HoangPhan spot on. Each product i.e. Bubble Tea has different variants (Sizes) at different prices. See Bubble Tea might have a size of Small $2.95, Medium $3.95 then Latte might be size of Short $3.95, Tall $4.95, Grande $5.95. So I want to display the relevant attribute (Size) and its variants for the correct product along with the price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is notice is that `Model.find_by_sql` will return a list of models and nothing more no matter what you select in your sql query.

So the solution I suggest is trying to convert to ActiveRecord::Relation like this:

```
Product.joins(:product_properties)
       .joins('INNER JOIN variant_properties on product_properties.property_id = variant_properties.property_id')
       .joins('INNER JOIN properties ON properties.id = product_properties.property_id AND properties.id = variant_properties.property_id AND properties.display_name = \'Size\'')
       .joins('INNER JOIN  variants on variants.product_id = products.id AND variants.id = variant_properties.variant_id')
       .pluck('products.id', 'LEFT(variant_properties.description,1)', 'variants.price')
```

I haven't tried yet but I think it could produce an array of arrays contains the value you need.

Comment: wasn't aware it only returned a list of models. ill give your suggestion a test and see what happens. thanks

Comment: that seems to return the correct query similar to above, but I guess the next issue I have is ensure that its only displaying the prices for the relevant product

Comment: another question for you, how do i separate out the results i have done what I thought would work in but it doesn't return the value @sizes.each do |size|
        - size.each do |var|
          = var.price

Comment: I think this comments box is not enough to express your idea, please post a new question for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541022/how-to-extract-values-from-a-custom-sql-query